# Is being asked to remove all personal belongings retaliation?

Tags: professionalism, management, colleagues, discrimination

After I complained about harassment the office manager was extremely angry with me and told me to remove all photos of my child from the office space. I only had one avatar photo of my daughter on my Skype.

[Is this response from management to a casual harassment claim appropriate?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/61360/is-this-response-from-management-to-a-casual-harassment-claim-appropriate)

I don't see the connection between harassment and a photo of a child but I felt that this was retaliatory behavior. The harassment wasn't even about the child.

I took the photo down and the manager talked to some harassers but then I was socially ostracized by the harassers.

Is any of the behavior retaliation?

Comment: You have 10 questions and 8 are about harassment.  3 about children and harassment.   8 questions are closed.  Yes it is retaliation.  They are tired of your harassment charges.

Comment: Are you asking us to read their minds, or are you asking for a legal opinion? Neither is on topic here. Voting to close.

Comment: I'd imagine you'll be under heavier scrutiny now than you were based upon all these questions you posted. It sounds to me like you are not really a fit for the particular workplace you're in.

Comment: Given all the questions about harassment, have you considered just getting another job?

Comment: @ChristopherEstep It does seem very odd to me that someone would stay in such a place especially in the degree of stress/frustration said harasser caused. I think it's time for the OP to consider cutting ties with the company or consulting a lawyer on the subject. It makes no sense to me to try and "fix" it by antagonizing everyone at the office. I would also say now the OP is on a thin line between getting fired or put on remedial tasks. Everyone will get sick of it especially if it is a constant ongoing problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it is retaliation.  Based on your question history you have made multiple harassment charges and many include children.